# Ruby minitest-ci gem

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, minitest

The documentation for the minitest-ci gem (seemingly the only option for producing test results for a CI tool such as Jenkins) has the extremely annoying habit of not preserving the results of `rake minitest:models` when invoked as `rake minitest` - the test results from running minitest:models are deleted prior to running the rest of the tests.  minitest-ci's barely-extant documentation claims adding this to test_helper.rb will disable the troublesome auto-clean behavior, but it doesn't:

```
# Why do SO and GitHub have to use completely different ways of indicating inline code?
# test/helper.rb
MiniTest::Ci.auto_clean = false
```

Has anyone out there managed to get minitest-ci to preserve *all* the test result files?  I'm reaching wits' end here.

Answer (score 0):

I think [ci_reporter gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ci_reporter) supports miniTest.  This could be another option.

Comment: It claims it does, but I can't seem to get that to report test results at all, and there seems to be no helpful documentation in this regard...